# Neovim cannot find color scheme 'tokyonight'

Tags: neovim, colorscheme

I'm on pop!_os and I'm trying to get [Tokyonight](https://github.com/folke/tokyonight.nvim) to work with Neovim, but I recieve the following error when I start Neovim:

```
Error detected while processing /home/username/.config/nvim/init.vim:
line    1:
E185: Cannot find color scheme 'tokyonight'
```

I've installed the lastest version of Neovim (0.5.0) and I am using vim-plug to manage plugins. My config path looks like the following

```
~/.config/nvim/
autoload/ init.vim vim-plug/
```

I've added the following to my init.vim as stated in the Tokyonight github and vim-plug docs

```
colorscheme tokyonight
source $HOME/.config/nvim/vim-plug/plugins.vim
```

I've successfully added the Tokyonight to my ./vim-plug/plugins.vim file and installed the plugin using vim-plug in neovim, but I still receive this error and I'm honestly lost as to why this is happening.

Comment: Find `colors/tokyonight.vim` in your local vim dir then make sure the parent of that `colors` directory is found in the paths stored in `:set rtp?` That's the first thing I'd check.

Comment: looks like it's there. `:set rtp` shows that `~/.config/nvim/autoload/plugged/tokyonight.nvim` is in the run time path which holds `./colors/tokyonight.vim`

Answer (score 3):

The error I made is placing the `colorscheme` command before the `source` command. `init.vim` should look like the following:

```
source $HOME/.config/nvim/vim-plug/plugins.vim
colorscheme tokyonight
```

Comment: I actually noticed that but got distracted before I could comment. Glad you found it.